# How to add 2 netcdf files with NCO?

Tags: addition, nco

I have two gridded netcdf files with several variables including also time.

The files have the same dimension (gridded, time, variables). The number of the variables are the same. However , the name of them are different.
For example

```
File1: var1_co, var2_co, var3_co
File2: var1_mo, var2_mo, var3_mo
```

The new file would be:

```
File3: var1_mo+var1_co, var2_co+var2_mo, var3_co+var3_mo
```

The following command does not work:

```
ncbo --op_typ=add File1.nc File2.nc File3.nc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, and possible re-rename on the back-end too:

```
ncrename -v var1_mo,var1_co -v var2_mo,var2_co, -v var3_mo,var3_co File2.nc f2_tmp.nc
ncbo --op_typ=add File1.nc f2_fmp.nc File3.nc
```